# Binding child of band Infragistics Hierarchical Data Grid to jsonResult

Tags: c#, json, html, razor, infragistics

I have a hierarchical data grid that recieves data from a json call fine.  But I have problems with the child band.  I don't know if it is the code or how the data is presented within the list from the json call.

```
    <table id="hierarchicalGrid"></table>

     <script type="text/javascript">

    var data = @MyData.AsRawJson()

    $("#hierarchicalGrid").igHierarchicalGrid({  
        dataSource: data,
        odata: true,
        initialDataBindDepth: -1,
        autoGenerateLayouts: true,
        autoGenerateColumns: false,
        primaryKey: "Username",
        columns:
           [{ key: "Username", headerText: "Username", dataType: "string" },
            {key: "EmplID", headerText: "EmplID", dataType: "string" },                
            {key: "Comment", headerText: "Comment", dataType: "string" }],            
        features:
            [{name: 'Paging',
                type: "local",
                pageSize: 50},
            { name: "Resizing"},
            { name: 'ColumnMoving' }],
        columnLayouts: [
                {
                    key: "GroupName",                        
                    primaryKey: "GroupName",
                    foreignKey: "GroupMembers",
                    autoGenerateColumns: false,
                    columns: [
                        { key: "GroupName", headerText: "UserName", dataType: "string", width: "100px" },
                        { key: "GroupDescription", headerText: "GroupDescription", dataType: "string", width: "100px" },
                        { key: "GroupMembers", headerText: "GroupMembers", dataType: "string", width: "100px" }
                    ], 
                    features: [
                        {
                            name: "Sorting",
                            type: "local"
                        }]

                }]
    });

</script>
```

The data comes as follows

```
    [username],[EmplID],[comment],[GroupName],[GroupDescription],[GroupMembers]
```

with UserName,EmplID, and Comment repeating with the same values per username while values for GroupName, and GroupDescription continue to be unique.  GroupMembers has the same data as UserName.  All of the data is coming from a view, which is a join from Users ([username],[EmplID],[comment]) and Groups ([GroupName],[GroupDescription],[GroupMembers]).  I would like a single row for UserName,EmplID, and Comment as if it were a groupby then expanding the child band would show [GroupName] and [GroupDescription].

When the initial grid opens, I get repeating rows of [username],[EmplID],[comment] and when I try to expand the child band, it throws a errormessage displaying:

```
    Unable to get value of the property '_injectGrid': object is null or undefined.
```

For what its worth, this is written on C# Razor pages using ServiceStack to Bootstrap.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.